# How to set continues labels in Matlab Pattern Recognition Toolbox (PRTools)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, regression, data-science

I have a dataset with labels and datapoints, problem is that rather then a classification problem I want to get a linair estimator, for example :

```
dataset=prdataset([2,4,6,8]',[1,2,3,4]')
testset=prdataset([3,5,7,9]')
classifier=dataset*ldc %should probably be changed?
result=testset*classifier
```

`result.data` now becomes

```
ans =

  1.0e-307 *

    0.2225    0.2225    0.2225    0.2225
    0.2225    0.2225    0.2225    0.2225
    0.2225    0.2225    0.2225    0.2225
    0.2225    0.2225    0.2225    0.2225
```

which is very wrong.

Ideally it would be `[1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5]'` or something to close to it. Any idea how to do this in PRtools or in something simulair? This is a linair dependancy but I would also like to be able to play around with other types of dependancies?

Also it would be a huge bonus of the system was somewhat clever about NaN values which heavily polute my real dataset.

I have already found that linearr class but when I use that I get weirdly sized datasets in return,

```
dataset=prdataset([2,4,6,8]',[1,2,3,4]')
testset=prdataset([3,5,7,9]')
classifier=dataset*linearr%should probably be changed?
result=testset*classifier
```

gives me the values

```
    0.1000   -0.3000   -0.7000   -1.1000
   -0.5000   -0.5000   -0.5000   -0.5000
   -1.1000   -0.7000   -0.3000    0.1000
   -1.7000   -0.9000   -0.1000    0.7000
```

which is again incorrect.

In chat they suggested using .* instead of * that resulted in Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

```
Error in linearr (line 42)
      beta = prinv(X'*X)*X'*gettargets(x);

Error in prmap (line 139)
      [d, varargout{:}] = feval(mapp,a,pars{:});

Error in  * 

Error in dyadicm (line 81)
    v1 = a*v1;     % train first mapping

Error in prmap (line 139)
      [d, varargout{:}] = feval(mapp,a,pars{:});

Error in  *
```

In the linearr code.

Just to be clear I'm looking for a way to, given a large set of values find the set of polynomials that best describes their relation (where the polynomials that are considered is a parameter of the program, in the example 1st order). So in our example the polynomial is 1/2a+0. In my final version I want to use a larger number of parameters (10-20) and it may require quadratic estimation.

Comment: It's a bit unclear exactly what you are asking? You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for tips on posting a reproducible example. What are `prdataset` and `ldc`?

Comment: @mgilbert ldc and prdataset are default parts of the prtools, If you install it (http://prtools.org/) then you can just plug this code in. ldc is a linair discriminant classifier and prdataset is well a dataset in the prtoolkit. For what I'm asking is a way to get continues predicted labels in the prtools system, in this toy example I want it to learn that the label is half of the input data.

Comment: ldc uses syntaxes like `LDC(R,S,M)` but you are just multiplying it...You are either not showing the whole code or have not read the docs.

Comment: @Oleg I use the syntax     [W,R,S,M] = A*LDC(R,S,M); where R S and M are all optional parameters which means that you can leave it empty, if you don't believe me install prtools and try it! http://37steps.com/prtools/examples/ shows how the fisherc can be used like the ldc. ldc works just like the value of pi.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Neural Network (neural network toolbox):
https://es.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html

From that link:

*Neural networks are good at fitting functions. In fact, there is proof that a fairly simple neural network can fit any practical function.*

*Suppose, for instance, that you have data from a housing application. You want to design a network that can predict the value of a house (in $1000s), given 13 pieces of geographical and real estate information. You have a total of 506 example homes for which you have those 13 items of data and their associated market values.*

*You can solve this problem in two ways:*

- Use a graphical user interface, nftool, as described in [Using the
  Neural Network Fitting Tool](https://es.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html#f9-43356).
- Use command-line functions, as described in [Using Command-Line Functions](https://es.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html#f9-33554).